# LDAP/Active Directory search excluding sAMAccountName with spaces

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I am integrating with 3rd party LDAP where some sAMAccountName contains spaces e.g sAMAccountName=Ishan Liyanage

Is there any possibility that I can exclude sAMAccountName with spaces while searching?

I know I can use logical not to exclude those, but it not an option as there so many with spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can add the logical negation of spaces using an additional search term like:

```
!(sAMAccountName=* *)
```

but, TBH, why such a restriction - is it for linux interop? If that's the case then you can use the `uid` field or the prefix of the principal name: `userPrincipalName=<user>@*`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but in my case that 3rd party application is not allowing to have spaces in sAMAccountName and logicial negation also not supported.

Comment: Then you're hosed. Your other alternative is to use a check after inputting the username to reject inappropriate user names